# google calendar iCal feed

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, icalendar, feed

I am working at a web portal that has a events section.
I have created using DDay.iCal a iCal "feed" with all the events.
Is there a possibility to make a link to this feed, and when clicked, the feed to be automaticly added to google calendar? (Something similar to RSS feeds, when you click them you can select use google reader). Or should I forget about using iCal and start reading about Google API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried to do the same thing myself; however, Remember the Milk seems able to put a link on their page that adds their calendar to Google Calendar. You can see it in action [here](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/googlecalendar/).

From what I can see, the way it is done is to link to **http://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=*[your public calendar iCal feed URL]***. This way, the user is directed to Google Calendar and is given an option to add the requested calendar to their list of calendars. It seems that the name of the calendar is taken form the value of the "**X-WR-CALNAME:**" attribute inside the calendar feed.

As I said, I have not tested this, so usual disclaimers apply and YMMV.