# What is the Office365 calendar feed URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, office365, icalendar

The scenario I'm trying to solve for is this: as a User who wants an organization's events on my Outlook/Office365 calendar, I want to be able to download and important a calendar from a link without first having it download and then me have to search for the file to import to my calendar. I want the process to be (mostly) automatic. I want the process to be similar to how I can do in Google Calendar, or in Yahoo Calendar.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479067/google-calendar-ical-feed/1479310#1479310) gives a link for programmatically adding a feed to Google calendar, which works! Now I need a similar url for Office365 ([another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199846/error-500-when-trying-to-subscribe-to-ical-calendar-feed-in-yahoo-calendar) gave me one for Yahoo). I have searched everywhere, but almost all the answers I've found don't answer this question; rather, they simply say how to add individual events, not feeds. Or they tell the user how to manually subscribe. In my case, I have the feed all ready to go (it's an .ics file), I just need to give the user a clickable link so the process of adding it can happen automatically, with the usual sign in/permissions that Office 365/Outlook requires.

So what is the URL for Office 365 that I can use to create a link to my ical/ICS feed like with the other two services?

EDIT: To clarify - I have the calendar already in an .ics file, and then when the user clicks the link, their Office365 should open and ask if they want to import the calendar, the way gmail does. How do I make that happen?

Comment: See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook/publishing-an-o365-calendar/68b7c153-3fcf-41ec-8ba8-f5417e83b725?auth=1

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev - that is opposite of what I want. I have the calendar already in an .ics file, and then when the user clicks the link, their Office365 should open and ask if they want to import the calendar, the way gmail does.

Answer (score -1):

And the half answer is the `webcal` protocol. [Webcal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcal) mostly does what I want. I have to change the URL to include the different protocol and voila! I get prompted on Windows about what I want to do with the link. The same thing happens on Mac.

The link looks like this - `webcal://myhost.com/myical.ics`. Unfortunately, it doesn't connect to Office365 as I've seen other services do, but when I attempt to view their code, it's obscured or otherwise unavailable. But this gets me much closer to where I need to be.

Answer (score -1):

Re *So what is the URL for Office 365 that I can use to create a link to my ical/ICS feed like with the other two services?*

There is no such URL.   There are instructions for an Office365 user on how to import or subscribe a calendar. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-subscribe-to-a-calendar-in-outlook-on-the-web-503ffaf6-7b86-44fe-8dd6-8099d95f38df

If you intend that the calendar will be updated, then leading your users to subscribe to a URL that you update is a better way to go about it.

Imports are really only good for one off calendars that do not change.

Note that Webcal is an Apple unofficial identifier for .ics and is not the answer for cross platform, although many applications will cope with it.

How a calendar file (ics url) gets treated depends on how it is accessed and how the individuals default application settings has been setup.  My browser settings for example are set to open .ics files in Notepad++ because I test/work with calendars.  Most will have it open their calendar application.  Then it also depends on the application.

Comment: If you click on the "Add to Calendar" link and choose "Office 365" at [this url](https://www.addevent.com/documentation/add-to-calendar-button), it will take you to your Office 365 login. How did they do that? There must be a link or something...

Comment: That is a javascript button that passes a parameters (like a GET form post) to the chosen calendar service.  The parameters would be calendar application dependent.  I don't use office365, but here is the google calendar version. https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?text=Summary+of+the+event&dates=20200714T080000/20200714T100000&ctz=America/Los_Angeles&details=Description+of+the+event&location=Location+of+the+event&pli=1&uid=1593478407addeventcom&sf=true&output=xml.

Comment: You described wanting to use your ics file or url.   See addevents documentation - they are offering a service which is quite different from the ics url approach.  See for example https://www.addevent.com/updates - the section headed "Adding events to Outlook.com and Office 365"

Comment: My answer stands.  For what you said you were trying to do.   "create a link to my ical/ICS feed".   An ics feed is already the link.  It then depends what the persons default file handler does.  like here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/ics-files-open-in-calendar-app-instead-of-microsoft-office/m-p/1235459.  The other methods you have linked to in your question are not passing the ics feed but are using the tools provided by the calendar services.

Comment: your link to the "updates" gave me a better direction, and it looks like there is a URL, but it basically can't be an .ics file, it has to be a POST, with the parameters I used to build the .ics file. It's the Microsoft Calendar API, and it's this api call: (I think) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#CreateAnEvent

Comment: Yes this is what I have been saying.   There is no ics url dedicated to office365, only the standard ics feed.  However many of the calendar services allow one to post/pass event parameters to a url of theirs (ie NOT an ics url)